# Running recurring job inside Startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, scheduled-tasks, hangfire

If I have a recurring job that will be run daily inside the .net core application. For that purpose, I'm thinking to use the Hangfire library.

> My question is: will placing this code for executing this daily job
> here in the Configure method be the most logical place or you would
> suggest something else?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IBackgroundJobClient backgroundJobs, IHostingEnvironment env)
{    
    app.UseHangfireDashboard();
    backgroundJobs.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello world from Hangfire!"));
    ...            
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your code is written it won't trigger daily, unless you restart your application on a daily basis.
Also, if you you have multiple instances of your application, you will get multiple runs of your background job.

What you need to write should be something like :

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate( "MyConsoleJobUniqueId",
                          () => Console.WriteLine("Hello world from Hangfire!"),
                          Cron.Daily );
```

As said by @BrandoZhang this code would be better placed in `appLifetime.ApplicationStarted` event handler.

Answer (score 3):

Asp.net core provide a `IHostApplicationLifetime`  which provide the methods which could be triggered when the application host has fully started, when the application host has performed a graceful shutdown, when the application host is performing a graceful shutdown.

I think you could put this method inside the IHostApplicationLifetime's ApplicationStarted method will be good.

More details about how to use it, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0#ihostapplicationlifetime-1).