# Prevent multiple servers to run the same job in Hangfire

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, hangfire

I run multiple instance of my application, and I have configured Hangfire to run as part of my `Startup.cs` configurations.

I want to generate a monthly report, and I'd like to ensure it's getting enqueued **only once**. [`DisableConcurrentExecution`](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/throttling.html) doesn't help as it prevents **execution** in the same time.

I read about [`Mutex`](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/throttling.html#mutexes) as well:

> When we create multiple background jobs based on this method, they will be executed one after another on a best-effort basis with the limitations described below. If there’s a background job protected by a mutex currently executing, other executions will be throttled (rescheduled by default a minute later), allowing a worker to process other jobs without waiting.

According to my understanding, `Mutex` will prevent concurrent execution, but it'll run my reports X times (where X is the number of my instances), one after another.

- How can I ensure to enqueue a cron job only once?
- How can I add the job without having to call it through an endpoint (e.g. `POST <server>/api/enqueue_jobs`

I don't have snippets to provide because I'm stuck with the configuration itself, I hope this answer won't be closed because I put efforts in trying to solve it by my own.

Comment: Manually manage that. From my experience Hangfire is really bad for singleton jobs. Just create some object of synchronization between services (in database, for example if they are on different machines). I usually just decide MASTER and SLAVES, then enqueue all singleton jobs to master - this way i dont need to care about mutexes and various race-condition bullshit.

Comment: @eocron Thanks for your response. Do you know if Quartz supports what I want to achieve?

Comment: @eocron I ran App Service in Azure, and I have auto-scaling, so my servers pool is dynamic and I don't really have master and slaves.

Comment: By default - no, dont know. I managed lifetime of my jobs through some scoped object, manually. Be it in db, file, or in memory.

Comment: @eocron So basically you're suggesting that I first get the job from the queue in the DB, and if it exists, skip the enqueue?

Comment: Quartz does support clustering - https://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/quartz-net-cluster-sql-azure-asp-net

Comment: Just allow multiple jobs at a time, If its already running (update status from time to time) - skip execution.

Comment: @eocron Good idea, but the only problem for me is that I'll see that the job is enqueued X times (if I have X servers).

Comment: @eocron Last question - how'd you suggest to register all jobs? I want cron jobs to be created when I start the program (in Java, it's a matter of annotation and each class that implements a "Job" interface will be collected by Spring).

Comment: I usually use persistent queue of sort to "register" jobs, or "produce" jobs, then consumers do those jobs in specific lifetime scope (per machine, per cluster, per something else). Kafka, event-hub, rabbit, etc.  And have some sort of scope storage - where it stores scope id and status and also ways to map some parameters to scope id. I usually show this to final users, not my queue.

Comment: I guess this may help scheduling only one job per month
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71334121/1236044